# printf before assert doesn't work

Tags: c, printf, assert

I think I've seen this issue before and I bet there's better solution out there so asking..

During debugging I found that any `printf` before `assert` don't work well. They're simply not printed most of the time. I tried adding `fflush(stdout`) but it doesn't seem to help.

Any other thoughts or alternatives?

Example:

```
printf... <- not printed
printf... <- not printed due to the assert. stdout not flushed?

do something

assert()
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: "better solution"? what is your solution?

Comment: I just tried a small program that does `printf("Hello\n"); assert(0);`.  It prints "Hello" and then aborts.

Comment: What are your platform and compiler? Are those something obscure?

Comment: How did you determine that assert() is causing printf() not to print? Are you sure your program isn't terminating in "do something" without executing your assert()? When assert() fails, it prints to stdout and then calls abort() which terminates the program and flushes all the buffers.

Comment: @Keith: Hardly impossible. The reason OP's experiencing this is obvious even without seeing any code. It's a classic buffering misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Call `fflush(stdout)` before `assert`. Or, if stdout has not been redirected and refers to the terminal, just writing a newline at the end of your message should be sufficient. By default, stdout is buffered (line buffered on terminals; fully buffered otherwise) and thus output will not actually be written until the output buffer overflows or a newline (in line-buffered mode) or `fflush` is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling with optimization - because the actual order of the printfs/assert may not be what you expect.